# Custom content type in Symfony2 Assetic (phpless)

Tags: symfony, less, content-type

I'm using Phpless(0.3.0) to compile less css in Symfony(2.4.2) automatically

My files:

**config_dev.yml**

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: true
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        lessphp:
            apply_to: "\.less$"
            formatter: "compressed"
            preserve_comments: false
```

**view.twig:**

```
{% stylesheets 'application/assets/less/bootstrap.less' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

---

So, in the response, everything is compiled.. but the content type of the generated css (that comes from symfony controller (use_controller: true)) is **"text/html"**

```
4798dcc_bootstrap_1.css GET 304  text/html login:20 0 B 320 ms
```

---

There are any setting of workaround to return this content type as **text/css**?
Taking into account that is the development environment, and I want avoid to generate manually the css with:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bug, https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/pull/263

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be with `fos_rest` catching all requests

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/, priorities: [html], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: false }
```

Add rule before that to exclude your assets